# (Feed Me) Request Method

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I am trying to import data but the remote API only allows `POST` requests for this endpoint. I have looked into the docs as well as Guzzle but can’t seem to find info on how to change the request method to `POST`.

Craft Version is 3.7.61 and Feed Me Version is 4.5.3

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with feed me itself

configuration options are here: https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html#control-panel
maybe forking feed-me repo and changing requests to POST is a solution

but there are two other solutions:

- fetching result as JSON from API via custom PHP code, upload it to the server and use this JSON file as feed input
- writing a custom plugin:

you should have a custom controller and action which it has logic to fetch JSON data from API via CURL and return it like:

> ```
>    return $this->asJson([
>         'jsonData' => $jsondata,
>         'hasNext' => $hasNext, // optionally if there are a lot of data and your API supports data pagination
>     ]);
> ```

remember you should register this controller action on your plugin as a site URL, so feed me can access this URL

```
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
    function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        $event->rules['plugin-handler/controllername/actionname'] = 'plugin-handler/controllername/actionname';
    }
);
```

finally, if this plugin is not on your local, you need to provide some basic authentication like a token over HTTPS on your action.
in this case, your feed URL is like `https://yoirsite/plugin-handler/controllername/actionname?token=xyz` and you should validate this token before returning data via action

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I guess that makes sense. Will give that a go.